# Flutter failed to build iOS app after installing macOS Sonoma and Xcode 15.0.1

Tags: flutter, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode15, macos-sonoma

Everything worked fine until the updates of both macOS and Xcode. After 2 days of search about similar error i ended app making the question since my thesis is due to next week and I'm going crazy... any help is welcome. Thanks in advance. Error message is below.

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Plus in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            7.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Plus.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved but moving the whole project file outside of cloud.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).